# rsync stop before filesystem full

Tags: rsync

I would like to implement a rsync that should stop if the destination filesystem free space goes down to less than 10G and I wonder what is the best way to do so?

I'm running on Linux RedHat 5.2

A quick and dirty solution could be to launch a process which will loop every second, check the free space and kill rsync accordingly but it's really bad I think.

Do you know a better way to do that? Maybe I miss something but rsync has not such option.

One last thing: I'm not rsync only, if another sofware exists and do the same thing with such an option, I can change.

Thanks a lot for your help
Rémi

Comment: It seems to me that that's what quotas are for.

Comment: Hi, I did not think about it because for me quotas are user or group based. In my case I do a rsync as root for files owned by many differe,t users and groups. So is there any way to set a quota at runtime (just before launch the rsync command) on the filesystem itself ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be done is:

- on the client, do a dry run first and extract the estimated transfer size from its output.
- on the client, pass this number to remote rsync somehow; the `--checksum-seed` option could work
- on the server, `pre-xfer exec` extracts that number from `RSYNC_ARG*` variables, checks available space and rejects entire transfer if it's not enough.